# How to get all possible combinations of a list in Netlogo (without value duplications in the list & using Netlogo)

Tags: list, combinations, permutation, netlogo

I am struggling to write a Netlogo program that could allow me to find all combinations from a list. Below is one example of my situation I want to model.

I have a list of five agent: [agent1, agent2, agent3, agent4, agent5] I want to know how to get all the possible combinations and the combinations must be with a fixed size (e.g. if size = 3, then the combination scenarios should be [agent1, agent2, agent3], [agent1, agent2, agent4],[agent1, agent2, agent5],[agent1, agent3, agent4], ..........

in this way, I would be able to work out a cost performance from each unique combination where 3 agents can interact with each other to determine that cost, and I would be able to find the best combination (i.e. the best 3 agents who can work together to deliver the minimal cost).

I need a mass production way to do this work in Netlogo modelling environment so that later on I could change the parameters such as size and the total number of agents. Appreciate for the code demonstration!

Answer (score 2):

```
to-report comb [_m _s]
  if (_m = 0) [ report [[]] ]
  if (_s = []) [ report [] ]
  let _rest butfirst _s
  let _lista map [? -> fput item 0 _s ?] comb (_m - 1) _rest
  let _listb comb _m _rest
  report (sentence _lista _listb)
end
```